# Angular 2 apache Virtual host getting error?

Tags: apache, angular, virtualhost

I am trying to run an angular app using my Apache virtual host configuration and i am getting error . My virtual host config file is below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapp.app
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/src
 <Directory /var/www/myapp/src>
        Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
</Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And the console error I am getting is 
[image]

I looked through solutions provided in stack overflow that is how I made my Apache virtual host files.

Comment: As far as I can see, you don't have problem with Apache, but with Angular. Your app is retrieved and you got runtime error.

Comment: yeah you are right figured out the issue nodemodules were not packed under root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual host files are what specify the configuration of our separate sites and dictate how the Apache web server will respond to various domain requests.

To begin, we will need to set up the directory that our virtual hosts will be stored in, as well as the directory that tells Apache that a virtual host is ready to serve to visitors. The sites-available directory will keep all of our virtual host files, while the sites-enabled directory will hold symbolic links to virtual hosts that we want to publish. We can make both directories by typing:

sudo mkdir /etc/httpd/sites-available
sudo mkdir /etc/httpd/sites-enabled

Note: This directory layout was introduced by Debian contributors, but we are including it here for added flexibility with managing our virtual hosts (as it's easier to temporarily enable and disable virtual hosts this way).

Next, we should tell Apache to look for virtual hosts in the sites-enabled directory. To accomplish this, we will edit Apache's main configuration file and add a line declaring an optional directory for additional configuration files:

sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Add this line to the end of the file:

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

Save and close the file when you are done adding that line. We are now ready to create our first virtual host file.

Start by opening the new file in your editor with root privileges:

sudo nano /etc/httpd/sites-available/example.com.conf

Note: Due to the configurations that we have outlined, all virtual host files must end in .conf.

First, start by making a pair of tags designating the content as a virtual host that is listening on port 80 (the default HTTP port):

```
# Client AngularJS application
DocumentRoot /var/www/example/client/public

# Server Laravel 4 API application
Alias /api /var/www/example/server/public

# Rewrite all requests in /api to server index.php
<Location /api>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /api/index.php [L]
</Location>
```

sudo ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/example.com.conf /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/example.com.conf
sudo ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/example2.com.conf /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/example2.com.conf